# Bind Node routes to backbone routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am trying to link routes from my node backend to some a view from my front-end.
The goal is to have a password-protected section (accessible at /admin) where we can add new blogposts. So at some point, I want to be able to render a login template, and if the user authenticates, display a form where he can create new blog posts.

Here's the github of the project: https://github.com/quantumlicht/collarbone/tree/master/q-trivia_stacked

I created a route on the server in *server/routes/blog_admin.js*
this serves to /admin and the template contains a div with an id that would normally contain a backbone view, but it does not and this is why I am trying to figure out, but I could not find examples on the web.

In my backbone routers files I have the admin routes defined that serves a correct view, but it does it only if I go to /#admin.

Is there a way I can tie this BlogPostContainerView to /admin ? Do I need to use a different router ? Is it something I need to do on the server or the front-end code ?

I am fairly new with this framework, so dont hesitate to share best practices or a better solution perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client-side routes (registered in your Backbone router) are completely separate from server-side routes (registered with expressjs).  Backbone routes work by examining the anchor tag in the URL in your browser's address bar (indicated by the presence of the #hashtag character followed by some text).  When Backbone sees "#/admin" in your address bar it creates and renders a view; when "/admin" is in your address bar Backbone ignores it and your browser treates it like any other HTTP GET request, and invokes the /admin route on the server.

Typically in a Backbone webapp you will register a route function in your router which creates a model and a view.  The model has a proerty called `url` which points to some location on your server; Backbone fetches data stored at that location and stuffs it into your model.  Your view then uses the contents of that model to render some HTML on screen:

```
var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  "routes": {
    "users/admin": "getAdmin"
  },

  "getAdmin": function() {
    var model = new MyModel();
    var view = new MyView({
      "model": model
    });

    model.fetch({
      "success": function() {
         view.render();
      }
    });
});

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  "url": "/admin"
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  "render": function() {
    $("body").append($("<p>" + JSON.stringify(model.attributes) + "</p>"));
  }
});
```

Note that this example expects your server to return just a bunch of JSON when the model makes its request to "/admin".  This won't work quite right with your current server-side route, which renders and returns a bunch of HTML instead of an object or an array.

In my experience, when you're using Backbone to create a single-page webapp you do all the HTML on the client side and just use your server to send it data.  I suppose you can use Backbone in conjunction with server-side rendering, but that to me feels kind of like using a screwdriver to hammer in a nail.

hope this helps!

Comment: I edited my post to specify, that the end goal is to create a password-protected section, it made sense to me to separate it from the core app, thus why i am trying to render templates on /admin instead of /#admin. Does it even make sense to do that ?

Comment: What Orze said.  Backbone doesn't look at anything before the #, and everything after the # is NEVER sent by the browser to the server.  You could maybe have /admin on the server render a page that sets the route in javascript to #something?